# Import Table in PE (.exe)

Tags: portable-executable

I found the pointer for the "Import Table" field. Which is 8 bytes in size and is divided into Virtual Address and Size. However the value in Virtual Address field is to big and is misleading my efforts to extract any information relating the whereabouts for entries relating to the Import Table. Is the value pointing to the offset, if so the (.exe) file finishes before reaching the desired offset.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The RVA (relative virtual address) of the Import Directory in the Directory Table must be valid. Perhaps your conversion of it into a physical offset is malfunctioning. Of course, that is done by traversing the section table to find the containing section. Then subtract that section's starting RVA from the target RVA. Then simply add the physical offset of the section to this result. That will give you the position within the file of the Import Directory. Conversions to and from RVAs to physical offsets may be necessary often if you are working with the on-disk file. If working with the in-memory image, sometimes protection utilities modify or destroy parts of the PE header in memory to deter dumping.

Once you get to the Import Directory you still have more work to do. A quick Google showed a better explanation than I'm likely to write here: http://sandsprite.com/CodeStuff/Understanding_imports.html

I am the author of the now 'classic' PECompact, PEBundle (now discontinued), and other PE manipulation utilities.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to find the import directory with hex editor?

Comment: I could, but why on Earth would you want to manually traverse a complicated data structure like a Portable Executable? Other than for learning purposes. Even for reversing, there are plenty of tools to reverse the PE structure (and much more). Anyway, basically it will just be finding and following the RVA, at the address designed by the file spec/data spec, to the import table.